# not inserting the data in sqLite using Java/JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have 2 Jtextfield and a button. name of Jtextfields are  Jtextfield1 and Jtextfield2 .i have tried the following code.I can't insert data in sqLite (Mozilla Firefox) using netbeans.

```
Statement st;

try {
   st=con.createStatement();
   st.executeUpdate("insert into emp(name,des) values ("+jTextField1.getText()+","+jTextField2.getText()+")");
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "pass");
   st.close();
   con.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fail");
}
```

Comment: Do you get any Exception ?

Comment: @Berger i got the result as "fail"

Comment: What if yuou do not handle the exception, so you can eactually see what is going wrong?

Comment: Yes, add e.printStackTrace() to know what happens .

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement`, you are wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i had tried PreparedStatement. but showing same error "Exceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: On which line does the NPE occur? It's probably the connection that is not properly initialized

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to encapsulate the strings with single quotes (''):

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into emp(name,des) values ('"+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"')");
```

To find out more information about your error, you should print the exception to the console like this:

```
[...]
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception: " + e) ;
[...]
```

Maybe this will help you to see what's wrong.

Comment: in exception it is showing as  : "Exceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Where is the connection 'con' object coming from?

Comment: the con means connection name with database. 
"connection con= null;"

Comment: You can't set it to null. You need to set it to a valid database connection. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: i have add sqlite manger and create a  database name "company" and I have create a table "emp". then i just copy the file "company.sqlite"  and paste into the application folder  . and gives following codes :Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:company.sqlite","","");
          Statement  st=con.createStatement();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "pass");
            
            
       } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fail");
        }

Answer (score 0):

@user5809644 I am following the bellow steps which is running in my system. Please follow the instructions and code .I think you will be get the result. You need to download  MySQL Community Server and MySQL Workbenchand and install ( if download and install not necessary).

then go to netbeans right click on Libraries select ***"add Jar/folder"*** then a window will appear. select netbeans folder (example:*C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ide\modules\ext* ) select mysql-connector-java5.1.23-bin.jar file. After successful install you can see that jar file to the libraries folder.

Then go to services (window>>services)  you can see ***databases*** . Right click on databases select new connection. A window will appear as name of "*new connection wizard*" . Select **mysql(connector/J Driver)** from drop-down and add the jar file which is already add i mention above (***(example:*C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ide\modules\ext* ) select mysql-connector-java5.1.23-bin.jar file.*** name Driver. Click on next>> you can see Driver name,host,database,user name,password (**note that if password is given in MySQL please enter the password also here**)
in JDBC url you can see the  ***jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull*** and then remove * ?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull*. then click on "***test connection***" button you will get result "sucess". Then click on next and then finish that process.

Then you can see in services >> databases>>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql.

Double click on it you can see a database name "mysql".

Click on it and then create table in table folder. (Here i have create a  table name "emp" and create some column names as name,address). You can create your own table and table columns also.

Go to your JForm  select sources then enter the code bellow

```
 import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Demoinsert extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection con= null;

    Statement st= null;

    PreparedStatement pt= null;
    /**
     * Creates new form Demoinsert
     */
    public Demoinsert() {
        initComponents();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","root");                
            jLabel3.setText("sucess");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("  "+e);
            jLabel3.setText("fail");
        }


    }


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try {
            String sql="insert into emp(Ename,Designation) values(?,?)";
           pt= con.prepareStatement(sql);
          pt.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
            pt.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
            jLabel3.setText("sucess");

            pt.execute();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("  "+e);
             jLabel3.setText("fail");

        }

    }
```

Comment: in this code  con= Drivermanger.getConnection ("") is mention is based on the link of JDBC url . (connectionlink/databasename,user id,password).

If password is blank mention it as "" only . do not enter any thing.

Here is my database user name and password is root. That is I have mention user id,password in that place as "root","root".